# How do you import c++ 11 into eclipse neon? My code is giving me errors and I heard that is the solution.

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

The if-statement is giving me an error and I don't know why.  Is it possible something is not imported?  The for loop is giving me a notice saying, "range-based loop for loop is a C++11 extension".

```
    string line;
    string temp = "";
    string beginning_time;

    void convertTimeintoInt(string beginning_time)
    {
      for(char a : beginning_time)
       {
        if(a == ":")
          continue;
       else
       temp += a;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error happens because you are comparing `char a` to string `":"`, instead of char `':'`. You are comparing apples and oranges here.

As for the C++11 warning, I don't know about Eclipse Neon but it seems strange to me that it would understand it enough to know what it is, but not actually support it. I'm guessing there is a switch somewhere you need to enable to get C++11 (or 14/17/...) support.

Comment: How would i fix the problem with the char and the string? The purpose of the if statement is to have a char that checks to see if there is a colon, and if there is it will skip over it.

Comment: @DavidGelovani Character literals use ' instead of ". It should be ':'.